# Link Elements to Keep Their Appearance In Sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing an iPad app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile and I'd like to create a preview pane in a carousel.  The preview pane would include a smaller version of each of the other panes, scaled so they fit inside the single pane.  The panes are not static and can be updated at any time using WebSockets, and the preview should be updated simultaneously.  There can also be any number of panes (although to keep things simple, assume an upper limit of 9).  For performance purposes, assume each pane can have upwards of 200 DOM objects attached to it.  To make it slightly more complicated, the carousel can exist on more than one different page.

I've been contemplating the best way to go about implementing this preview pane, and, before inventing a pair of Complicator's Gloves, would like to hear back from the community on any possible better strategies.

A couple methods I have been considering include:

1. Cloning each pane and then using a CSS transform to scale it to an appropriate size, based on how many panes there are, and then attaching the clones to the preview pane.
2. Store each pane as a jQuery object in a variable and draw each pane and the preview pane using that object (possibly necessitating redrawing the entire carousel every time there is an update, depending on how much effort I want to make identifying and updating deltas).
3. Repositioning all the panes so that they exist inside the preview pane when the preview pane is active (this might break the carousel, or at least make it look slightly bizarre as a user swipes a pane over but hasn't actually moved on to that pane yet).

Is there anything I'm missing?  It would be nice if there was an easy way to "link" two elements together to make one mirror the other, but apply different CSS to one or the other (for zooming).  I suppose it might be possible to do this by creating an event that would fire and then adding a listener to its clone, which would then copy the html of the updated element to itself (probably wouldn't be too terribly to difficult to write a jquery plugin to manage this).

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what phonegap allows for as far as rendering options go, but my first instinct would be to take a screen shot of the relevant pane. Perhaps phonegap has this built in?

Another option is a javascript library which will clone the DOM and create an HTML5 canvas element. You can either then display the canvas natively, or convert the canvas data in to image data.

Here is one such library: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Given the large number of elements needed, I would hesitate to clone those over and over again. However, if live previews are a necessity, that might be more efficient than using image files or the canvas. You could fire off the canvas draw function after major changes, but probably wouldn't want to do it after the end of every frame of animation.